# By creating an instance on EC2, will I be allocated a VM on a server in an Amazon data centre?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, virtual-machine, aws-cloudformation, aws-ec2-instance-connect

Im gathering some data on how AWS actually work.I got really confused on the relation between EC2 instance and VM on server at the data center.How are they actually connected?

Comment: EC2 instance is just another name of Virtual Machine in AWS world. When you create an EC2, AWS will create a Virtual Machine on some hypervisor server (physical server) placed inside a server rack inside a datacenter.

Comment: "A VM on a server in an AWS data center" is the definition of an EC2 instance.

Comment: There are some excellent videos on YouTube to explain Amazon EC2, such as: [AWS re:Invent 2019: Amazon EC2 foundations - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMMybKqC2Y0)